# Access file of windows machine from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-volume, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have installed **Docker Desktop for Windows** in Windows 10 operating system. 
I am running a python script inside docker container which reads file from disk and add few text at the end of files. Now the requirement is to read files from Windows 10 and perform the same operation on it.

Is it possible in docker to read files from OS on top of which Docker is running?

Answer (score 7):

Of course, you can use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).

For example, you can run the following command:

```
docker run -v path/to/your/file/on/host:path/to/the/file/on/container your_image
```

Comment: I think this is to accessing files of docker container from host machine. I want to read file of windows machine from docker container. ie: Python running inside docker container reading files of windows .

Comment: I think this is the only way to access the file from host machine .

Comment: @Himanshusharma  - But this command will run from outside of container right? I want to run program inside container(CentOS) and it should be able to access file of windows C:\test.txt.

Answer (score 5):

The only approach to access the host file is that you can mount the host directory of host system .
like if you have

c:\project\test.txt

you can mount c:\project to the docker .

docker run  -v c:/project:/src images 
By this way you will we able to access the c:project files inside the src folder of the container . or you can create the folder in container and mount it .

And files in container will we accessible to you in /src folder of container and you can do any operation with that file inside the container

Comment: If any query can ask.

Comment: If he is using virtualbox as docker-machine driver, he will not be able to mount volumes from outside his userhome (C:\Users\User) as far as I konw