# How to access d:/files directory/folder from docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, docker-container

I have node/express application running in docker using below `docker-compose` file,

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  serverapp:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: backend:5.1.5
    container_name: server_container
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine as backend-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --no-package-lock
COPY . ./
RUN npm prune --production
EXPOSE 5000
    
# stage-2

FROM node:14-alpine
COPY --from=backend-build /app /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:docker"]
```

after running docker-compose file, I create an image and a container successfully.

I'm able to access all APIs using POSTMAN. Now I have to read data from `D:/files` (windows machine local directory) in one of the APIs.

When I hit that particular api through POSTMAN, it throws one exception which I'm capturing in node app through exception handling mechanism and I get response as below,

```
{
    "message": "Exception occured : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'D:/files'"
}
```

Basically, inside such directory, I have to read different files so I need to access different files as well.

**How can I access windows directory and different files within it in docker container ?**

---

Also,

This directory is configurable by my users.

eg.

**config.js**

```
export const CONFIG={
   path: "D:/files"               
}
```

My users can change it to, let's say, `D:/data/files` or something else like `C:/data/abc/files` or anything.

SO, **How can I make it dynamic when I create container ?**

---

FYI, in local, everything works perfectly fine. It is just docker container in which it doesn't work.

Comment: do this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267457/access-file-of-windows-machine-from-docker-container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who look for solution can do following,

1. Set docker volume in your docker-compose file as shown below,

   ```
   version: '3.8'
   services:
     serverapp:
       build:
         context: ../
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
       image: backend:5.1.5

       volumes:
         - D:/files:/app/files                       <#### Mapping of your local directory to container directory

       container_name: server_container
       ports:
         - "5000:5000"
   ```

The above code will map your local directory to container directory but as you can see `D:/files` path is static path and not dynamic path.

2. If you want to make path or local directory dynamic, you can do following

Create `.env` file in the same directory in which your `docker-compose` file is and define one new variable as shown below,

**.env**

```
MY_LOCAL_DIRECTORY_PATH=D:/files               <#### you can set any path you want...
```

**docker.compose**

```
volumes:
      - ${MY_LOCAL_DIRECTORY_PATH}:/app/files  <#### Mapping of your local directory to container directory
```